# Google app Script newTrigger not apply trigger for external file

Tags: google-apps-script

`1hIQ-WfagWLPPdsDS8U1111111111111111111111111111111111` - is the `id` of the external file, but triggers apply to file, where I run the script. How can I apply trigger for the external file?

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('onEditQ')
      .forSpreadsheet('1hIQ-WfagWLPPdsDS8U1111111111111111111111111111111111')
      .onEdit()
      .create();
```

Comment: There are two types of Triggers in the [Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#top_of_page). From the [table](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#available_types_of_triggers), you will have a view what type of triggers are applicable for a specific event. If the [restrictions on simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions) keep them from meeting your needs, an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) might work instead.